# WordPress seems to rewrite absolute URLs in POST AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I was "asked" to develop a fairly complex application in a WordPress environment, I know I've been using unorthodox techniques but my available time was THREE DAYS. I have little experience with WordPress and I guess you can see why I couldn't possibly study the framework.

So, I've been using the ExecPHP plugin to include a .js file

```
[insert_php]
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . content_url() . '/spesa-prodotti/spesa.js"></script>';
[/insert_php]
```

Inside `spesa.js` I have a JQuery AJAX call

```
        $h.post({
        url: "http://www.isalaioli.it/_invia-spesa.php",
        data: _dataString,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Console says:

```
http://www.isalaioli.it/spesa-online/[object%20Object]
```

This means, I guess, that the URL gets rewritten.
Is there a workaround to prevent this?

Comment: use **[wp_enqueue_sript](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)** to include a new script.   `[object%20Object] ` suggests your data isn't a string. Is possible there is a global AJAX method like `$.ajaxPrefilter` elsewhere in site code  that is adjusting url

Comment: `_dataString = encodeURIComponent(_prodottiString) + $h(this).serialize();`

How can this be anything else than a string?

Comment: just noting what was displayed  `[object%20Object] ` sure looks strange